# Chave composta na migrate do laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, migrations

Gostaria de criar uma chave primaria dupla com um campo auto incremento "id" e o "período_letivos_id", mas dá erro e não sei qual a forma correta de se fazer, se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeceria muito!

Migrate

```
Schema::create('disciplinas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('periodo_letivos_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('periodo_letivos_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('periodo_letivos')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('cursos_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('cursos_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('cursos')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('periodo_regular')->nullable();
        $table->string('matriz_curricular')->nullable();
        $table->string('nome', 200);
        $table->string('abrev_nome', 15);
        $table->integer('professors_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('professors_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('professors')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('aulas', 3)->nullable();
        $table->string('aulas_hora', 3)->nullable();
        $table->string('obs', 400)->nullable();
        $table->primary(['id', 'periodo_letivos_id']);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

Comment: Tente usar $table->unsignedInteger('periodo_letivo_id');

Comment: Já tentei, mas não deu certo, precisava que esse campo fosse auto incremento também. Por exemplo não posso inserir a mesma disciplina no mesmo período 2 vezes!

Comment: Ja verificou se os dois campos estão exatamente na mesma tipagem ? int unsignd

Comment: Assim, se eu deixo o $table->increments('id')->unsigned(); e $table->integer('periodo_letivos_id')->unsigned(); ambos como unsigned e $table->primary(['id', 'periodo_letivos_id']); não dá certo, mas se ei coloco o id como integer e unsigned aceita mas ai perco o auto increnmento!

Comment: E se tu deixar os sem ser unsigned, fiz direto na tabela, mas deste modo é pra funcionar

Comment: Não aceitou adicionar a constrait de periodos letivos sem ser unsigned!

Comment: Seu banco está em qual engine ? MyISAM ou InnoDB

Comment: Eu estou utilizando MySql, como vejoqual engine?

Comment: Eu resolvi deixar o id sem incremento, sera que me ajuda a criar uma trigger que funcione?

Comment: preciso criar uma auto incremento

Comment: Tente colocando isso em shchema da tabela: $table->engine = 'InnoDB', se não resolver ai movo pro chat pra gente tentar resolver

Comment: Deu certo também não, estou tentando criar uma trigger mas não esta funcionando!

Comment: Resolvi de outra forma, alterei os campos para unsigned e depois da criação rodei um comando e alterei a estrutura do id para auto incremento! esperar pra quando for começar afazer as consultas pra saber

Comment: Boa, se não der certo reviva o tópico kk